# How can I use defined key in another key/value pair

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have this javascript object:

```
return {
   AccDocs: {
      query: function() {
         ...
      },
      deleteAndQuery: function() {
         ...
         AccDocs.query(); //Error: AccDocs is not defined
      }
   }
}
```

But, it returns an error that says `AccDocs is not defined`.
How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: By the way you are going to create `circular reference `.

Comment: @ozil — That won't create a circular reference, and even if it did: so what? There's no sign that any code is going to be trying to process it recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables and properties on objects are different things. You cannot access the property of an object without specifying which object you mean.

You can *probably* access it using the `this` keyword:

```
this.query();
```

Keeping in mind that the value of `this` will [vary depending on how the function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) (when `a.b.c.d.AccDocs.deleteAndQuery()` is called, `this` inside `deleteAndQuery` will be `AccDocs` as it is the first object to the left of the last `.`, but if you were to first copy `query` to another variable and then call `query()`, pass it to `setTimeout`, or if you were to use `call` or `apply` then the value of `this` would change).

For more robustness (but less flexibility, since being able to change the context can be useful) you can store your object in a variable which you can access by name.

```
var AccDocs = {
    query: function() {
            ...
    },
    deleteAndQuery: function() {
            ...
        AccDocs.query();
    }
};

return { AccDocs: AccDocs };
```

Comment: damn it. Ok, you won today. I'll delete my post. Today - is not my lucky day

Answer (score 1):

By using the `this` keyword:

```
return {
   AccDocs: {
      query: function() {
         ...
      },
      deleteAndQuery: function() {
         ...
         this.query(); //Here
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest — Of course it will return undefined, there is no return statement in it. I suspect you mean that the value of `this.query` will be undefined. It's possible, but depends on how the function gets called. Given the most likely code for calling it, it will work just fine and `this` will be the value of the `AccDocs` property.

Comment: The typical case being when you call `something.AccDocs.deleteAndQuery()` (as opposed to, for instance, `something.AccDocs.deleteAndQuery.call(something)`)